# Polymer drawer-panel wont close

Tags: polymer

I have a core-drawer-panel with a core-menu. I am able to open the drawerPanel when I click on a menu option. The problem I am having is that when I click on an item in the drawer Panel it does not close. I have added a javascript code at the bottom copied from the spa demo on polymer-projects, but it still doesn't close.

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="template">
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
        <core-header-panel drawer id="drawer">
            <core-toolbar id="navheader">
                <span>Menu</span>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-menu selected="{{option}}" on-core-selected="{{selectedOption}} valueattr="data-category">
                core-items...
            </core-menu>
        </core-header-panel>
    </core-drawer-panel>
</template>

<script>
    var template = document.querySelector('#template');
    var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
    var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');

    navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
        drawerPanel.togglePanel();
    });

    template.selectedOption = function(detail) {
        if(detail.isSelected) {
            drawerPanel.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is `on-core-selected="{{selectedOption}}` a typo? You are missing a **"**

Comment: Also the correct function is `drawerPanel.closeDrawer()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for the `template-bound` event before you can querySelector or add listeners to anything inside the template. Try rewriting it like this:

```
<script>
    var template = document.querySelector('#template');
    template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
        var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
        var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');

        navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
            drawerPanel.togglePanel();
        });

        this.selectedOption = function(detail) {
            if(detail.isSelected) {
                drawerPanel.close();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```